# Вычислить индекс элемента в наборе

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть следующие элементы:

```
<div>
  <a id="1" class="elem">
  <a id="2" class="elem">
  <a id="3" class="elem">
</div>
```

Получаем набор :

```
var collect = $('a.elem');
```

Как мне по известному id элемента определить его позицию в наборе(`index`), чтобы впослествии можно было получить нужный элемент с помощью `collect[index]`?

Comment: id не может быть просто числом. идентификатор должен обязательно начинаться с латинского символа и может содержать в себе латинские буквы (A–Z, a–z), цифры (0–9), символ дефиса (-) и подчеркивания (_). Использование русских букв в именах идентификатора недопустимо.

Comment: Не суть... это нечто псевдокода...

Comment: @co11ter, вы хотите по атрибуту определить индекс элемент, который входит в группу с классом .elem? Тогда [ничего не меняется][1]. Конечно, если в этой группе всего один элемент, у которого атрибут href имеет уникальное значение.

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/mrXm3/

Comment: Почему-то у меня возвращается -1, хотя написано так же... Разбираюсь.

Comment: @co11ter, если не разберётесь, то закиньте реальную часть html-структуры [в песочницу][1].

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: [Закинул][1]
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/GL9n8/7/

Comment: @co11ter, скорее всего, что вы пытаетесь выбрать первую ссылку, а значение её атрибута href повторяется ниже у другой ссылки. Я уже писал выше, что в таком случае работать не будет. Если попробуем выбрать последний элемент, то [всё работает][1].

P.S. Нет! Я не обратил внимание, что вы в селекторе класс указываете. Тогда в целом [должно работать][2].

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/GL9n8/8/
   [2]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/GL9n8/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо #aId - нужный ID элемента

```
console.log( $('#aId').index('.elem') );
```

Если надо еще больше сузить круг, то добавьте селектор родительского элемента:

```
console.log( $('#aId').index('div .elem') );
```

Comment: Отлично, то что надо!! А если нужно по `href`? Типа `$('a[href="'+href+'"]').index('.elem')`?